# Why the same LINQ expression behaves differently in two different foreach loops?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have following XML.

```
<Parts>
  <Part name="Part1" disabled="true"></Part>
  <Part name="Part2" disabled="false"></Part>
  <Part name="Part3" ></Part>
  <Part name="Part4" disabled="true"></Part>  
</Parts>
```

I want to remove the nodes for which `disabled` attribute is set to `true`. If 'disabled' attribute is not used for any 'Part' element, it means it's not disabled.

I wrote following code:

```
XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
List<XmlNode> disabledNodes = new List<XmlNode>();
foreach(XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes)
{
    if(node.Attributes["disabled"] != null && 
        Convert.ToBoolean(node.Attributes["disabled"].Value))
    {
        disabledNodes.Add(node);
    }
}

foreach (XmlNode node in disabledNodes)
{
    root .RemoveChild(node);
}
```

This code removes 2 nodes from the XML as expected.

I then wrote following code to make code compact:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Where(child => child.Attributes["disabled"] != null && 
    Convert.ToBoolean(child.Attributes["disabled"].Value)))
{
    root.RemoveChild(node); // This line works fine without any exception.
}
```

**I found that this loop iterate only once, removing only one node from the XML.**

---

EDITED QUESTION:

Now when I change the `foreach` loop, this time I convert the result of LINQ expression to the `List<T>` using `ToList()` method (as suggested by @Toni Petrina in his answer). And this time it works fine !

```
 foreach (XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>()
        .Where(child => child.Attributes["disabled"] != null && 
        Convert.ToBoolean(child.Attributes["disabled"].Value)).ToList())
    {
        root.RemoveChild(node); // This line works fine without any exception.
    }
```

**Why the use of `ToList()` made LINQ expression work in `foreach` loop as expected?** Any technical reason why result of LINQ behaves differently in two different situations?

I am using .NET 4.0.

Comment: Although there is obviously a problem. Your first method is most likely more efficient and readable, I would personally stick to that :)

Comment: Try putting what you're iterating over in a variable and use the debugger to check that. Maybe it's not working as expected for some other reason. e.g. I know you can't remove/add items in a list while iterating it, maybe that's the same with an `XmlNode`. You might be hiding an exception that is being raised.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are iterating through "root" and at the same time try to delete something from it which isn't allowed with the foreach loop

Comment: @Ivan Crojach Karačić: This is not a problem 'in this case' at least. I said it iterated once without any exception.

Comment: @CSharpLearner Remove the `RemoveChild()` code from the body of the `foreach` and see how many times it iterates?

Comment: @LukeHennerley: Presence of "RemoveChild" inside foreach has no issues at all. I can iterate through loop without any exception and I get the resulting XML without the node I removed in the foreach loop. So this is not an issue here at all.

Comment: I tried this code here: http://ideone.com/7gyQfj and got the error we are expecting (but you are not). Interestingly I tried on VSExpress 2012 and it worked as expected (removed all expected nodes).

Comment: I believe you are getting an exception but somehow it's not shown properly. What IDE are you using? Can you put a complete sample online using something like http://ideone.com/ as I have?

Comment: Read up on linq deferred execution for examples of why the `.ToList()` makes it work. (That's what fixes it, not moving it out of the `foreach` loop).

Comment: @George Duckett : I use VS 2010. And should IDE really matter? I think it's the runtime that should complain if that code is wrong. By the way, I use .NET Framework v 4.0.

Comment: @CSharpLearner: The IDE won't but the version of the framework might. Can you get a (non-)working example in ideone that demonstrates the problem you're having?

Comment: It is no longer the same query. When you iterate over an collection from LINQ, you are requesting one item at a time. And you change the collection from which you pull your items. If you didn't modify the collection, it would work fine. Just remember: don't change the collection while you are iterating over it.

Comment: @Toni Petrina: Thanks a lot. I think it's the answer to my question and you should post it as an answer, instead of comment. You will get 100 upvotes from me !

Comment: I've posted a question regarding why you don't see the exception in some cases. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682613/linq-xmlnodes-foreachs-and-exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Where(child => child.Attributes["disabled"] != null && 
    Convert.ToBoolean(child.Attributes["disabled"].Value)).ToList())
{
    root.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

I've added extra ToList() to force immediate execution of the LINQ expression.

When you create a LINQ query, you get an IEnumerable collection which doesn't actually hold any results. Even though you wrote all those Select and Where and many other clause, the complete query isn't executed **before** you start iterating over it. Only then is the actually query run.

In the original code, you created a query and started iterating over it. You received the first item that passes through all LINQ clauses and remove the first node. But since you were iterating over root collection which is now modified, the iteration stops.

You cannot change the collection you are iterating over in the body of foreach loop.

Comment: Iterating over an `IEnumerable` will execute it. The code the OP has written should iterate the same elements as the code you have written.

Comment: This might actually fix the issue (but for another reason). See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681431/why-linq-expression-in-foreach-loop-returns-wrong-result#comment22262136_15681431)

Comment: @LukeHennerley That might not be entirely true. Since the collection that is being iterated actually changes in the foreach body, forcing execution before iterating will prevent this problem.

Comment: @LukeHennerley So I went through the trouble of actually compiling the code and it works, who would have figured that :/

Comment: @Toni Petrina: When I am iterating the LINQ expression in `foreach` loop, am I not 'using' the returned collection? And why does it iterate even once if this is the case? 
I found that your suggestion to converting it to List<T> actually solved the issue. But i want to know why does it work like that. And so I edited my original question too.

Comment: @ToniPetrina: It might work, but your last sentence is misleading. The foreach loop does use the returned collection. EDIT: This comment made before CSharpLearner's

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you change collection when enumerate it. It is wrong. You should use something like this:

```
var disabledNodes = root.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Where(child => child.Attributes["disabled"] != null && 
    Convert.ToBoolean(child.Attributes["disabled"].Value)).ToArray();

foreach (XmlNode node in disabledNodes)
{
    root.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

**Update**

It is due to deffered execution. If you do not use ToArray() or ToList(), IEnumerator returns value one by one when you need next element (i.e. when foreach go to next turn). And when foreach execute first turn, your source become changed and iteration stopped. But if you call ToArray(), you get new variable that contains array of disabledNodes and foreach will not change collection that it iterates.

Comment: I know this can be done. But my question is 'why does not it work when the LINQ expression is directly written in the code'?

Comment: That as is currently written doesn't change anything. You need to add a `.ToList` or something otherwise you're still iterating the underlying list while removing.

Comment: Because my answer is actually correct. Everything done with LINQ is executed when requested, not when the statement ends.

Comment: @Toni Petrina: If this is the case, why did it execute even once?

Comment: Cause after first execution your source is changed and iteration stopped

Comment: @George, you are right, ToArray() or ToList() should be called.